# Evaluate IF subtree in homogeneus AST

Tags: tree, antlr, antlr3, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm building a tree walker for an homogeneus AST (all nodes have same class), what's the correct way to evaluate an if statement?

My AST for if are like this:
[image]

I would something that when parses an `IF` block, evaluates sequentially his `CONDBLOCK` children and if one of them is true, the tree walker doesn't evaluate the remaining.

More clearly, my tree walker is something like:

```
ifStat       : ^(IF { jump=false; } condition* defcond?) 
condition    : { if (jump) return retval; } ^(CONDBLOCK exp block) { jump=$exp.value; }
defcond      : ^(DEFAULT block)
```

My question is, if in the example `$op=+` so the first `CONDBLOCK` must be executed, I don't want evaluate anything else, I want execute the first `CODEBLOCK` and go up in my AST tree to evaluate the block after `if`.

Now I've implemented that with a flag and a check in `condition` rule that returns if the flag was true (that means another block is already been executed).

But `return retval;` completely stops the execution, I want just go up without evaluate remaining conditions. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Assuming you know how to evaluate expressions, surely the code for this practically writes itself?

Comment: I'm asking what's the antlr way to jump over the if subtree when an already true `CONDBLOCK` was found

Comment: I've clarified my question with a snippet of my walker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any kind of runtime evaluation from an AST that involves branching or jumps is probably going to get ugly. You may want to consider converting the AST into a series of more conventional operations and execute them in sequence. It's an extra step, but it will get you out of jams like this one and I think it's easier to verify and to debug than an AST evaluator.

With that out of the way, here is a way to skip evaluating subsequent `condition` and `defcond` rules. I'm sticking with the structure that you have, which means that evaluations have two distinct phases: a matching phase (`exp`) and an execution phase (`block`). This is only worth noting because the phases are handled in different parts of a subgraph and there is no natural means of jumping around, so they need to be tracked across the whole `if` statement.

Here's a simple class to manage tracking a single `if` evaluation:

```java
class Evaluation {
    boolean matched = false;
    boolean done = false;
}
```

When `matched` is true and `done` is false, the next `block` gets executed. After execution, `done` is set to true. When `matched` and `done` are both true, no more `block`s get executed for the remainder of the `if` statement.

Here are the tree parser rules to handle this:

```java
ifStat       
@init { Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(); }
             : ^(IF condition[eval]* defcond[eval]?) 
             ;

condition [Evaluation eval]
             : ^(CONDBLOCK exp {if ($exp.value) eval.matched = true;} evalblock[eval])
             ;

defcond [Evaluation eval] 
             : ^(DEFAULT {eval.matched = true;} evalblock[eval]) //force a match
             ;

evalblock [Evaluation eval]     
             : {eval.matched && !eval.done}? //Only do this when a condition is matched but not yet executed
                block                //call the execution code
                {eval.done = true;}  //evaluation is complete.
             | ^(CODEBLOCK .*)  //read the code subgraph (nothing gets executed)                
             ;
```

---

Here are the grammars and the code I used to test this:

#### TreeEvaluator.g (combined grammar to produce an AST)

```java
grammar TreeEvaluator;

options { 
    output = AST;
}

tokens { 
    CONDBLOCK;
    CODEBLOCK;
    DEFAULT;
}


compilationUnit : condition+ EOF;
condition   : cif elif* celse? -> ^(IF cif elif* celse?);
cif         : IF expr block -> ^(CONDBLOCK expr block);
elif        : ELIF expr block -> ^(CONDBLOCK expr block);
celse       : ELSE block -> ^(DEFAULT block); 
expr        : ID EQ^ ID;
block       : LCUR ID RCUR -> ^(CODEBLOCK ID);

IF  : 'if';
ELIF: 'elif';
ELSE: 'else';
LCUR: '{';
RCUR: '}';
EQ  : '==';
ID  : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+;
WS  : (' '|'\t'|'\f'|'\r'|'\n')+ {skip();};
```

#### AstTreeEvaluatorParser.g (tree parser)

```java
tree grammar AstTreeEvaluatorParser;

options { 
    output = AST;
    tokenVocab = TreeEvaluator;
    ASTLabelType = CommonTree;
}

@members { 
    private static final class Evaluation {
        boolean matched = false; 
        boolean done = false;
    }

    private java.util.HashMap<String, Integer> vars = new java.util.HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public void addVar(String name, int value){
        vars.put(name, value);
    }

}

compilationUnit : ifStat+;

ifStat       
@init { Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(); }
             : ^(IF condition[eval]* defcond[eval]?) 
             ;

condition [Evaluation eval]
             : ^(CONDBLOCK exp {if ($exp.value) eval.matched = true;} evalblock[eval])
             ;

defcond [Evaluation eval] 
             : ^(DEFAULT {eval.matched = true;} evalblock[eval]) //force a match
             ;

evalblock [Evaluation eval]     
             : {eval.matched && !eval.done}? //Only do this when a condition is matched but not finished 
                block                //call the execution code
                {eval.done = true;}  //evaluation is complete.
             | ^(CODEBLOCK .*)  //read the code node and continue without executing
             ;

block        : ^(CODEBLOCK ID) {System.out.println("Executed " + $ID.getText());};

exp returns [boolean value]
            : ^(EQ lhs=ID rhs=ID)
                {$value = vars.get($lhs.getText()) == vars.get($rhs.getText());}
            ;
```

#### TreeEvaluatorTest.java (test code)

```java
public class TreeEvaluatorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CharStream input = new ANTLRStringStream("if a == b {b} elif a == c {c} elif a == d {d} else {e}");
        TreeEvaluatorLexer lexer = new TreeEvaluatorLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        TreeEvaluatorParser parser = new TreeEvaluatorParser(tokens);

        TreeEvaluatorParser.compilationUnit_return result = parser.compilationUnit();

        if (lexer.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors() > 0 || parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors() > 0){
            throw new Exception("Syntax Errors encountered!");
        }

        AstTreeEvaluatorParser tparser = new AstTreeEvaluatorParser(new CommonTreeNodeStream(result.getTree()));
        tparser.addVar("a", 0);
        tparser.addVar("b", 2);
        tparser.addVar("c", 3);
        tparser.addVar("d", 4);
        AstTreeEvaluatorParser.compilationUnit_return tresult = tparser.compilationUnit();

    }
}
```

The test code evaluates `if a == b {b} elif a == c {c} elif a == d {d} else {e}`. The id between the `{}`s is printed if it is evaluated. So if `a == b` is true, then `"Executed b"` will be printed.

Variable values are assigned by calling `tparser.addVar(...)`. In this case, `a` doesn't equal any other variable, so block `{e}` is evaluated.

Comment: What I was looking for was the way to consume token without do nothing ( `^(CODEBLOCK .*)`), so your solution works perfectly. What do you mean with "... converting the AST into a series of more conventional operations ...", I want to learn more about. Thank you

Comment: @SalvatoreD. I'm glad I could help. The "more conventional operations" would be the kinds of operations that a compiled program uses to modify a program stack, registers, and/or memory. The operations can be represented as a list, so jumping is just a matter of moving the operation index ahead by the distance of the jump (or to the position of a label). Everything is linear, so it's easier for the programmer to read and to debug than when working with a tree graph. There's more code involved overall, but I think the payoff is worth it as a language gets more complex.

Comment: The DFA that predicts alternatives for rule `evalBlock`, can't see the parameter `eval`. I've tried to declare that parameter as a field, but something strange happens (a `FailedPredicateException` is raised), I think there is something wrong in that approach, could you help me? Thanks

Comment: @SalvatoreD. I'm not sure why you're getting that error. I updated my answer to show the full grammars and test code that I used originally. Maybe this will help. If not, consider writing up a new question since the problem is probably not related to your original one.